# How to correctly switch images with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have somewhat complex div structure on my page and I want to switch some images (on hover), but I can't directly set hover with css because the image I want to make hover on is behind another transparent image. Therefore I have created transparent overlay on the top. When the overlay is hovered, specified div's background is switched.

HTML:

```
<div id="image"></div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: url(myImage.jpg);
}

#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

and here is jQuery doing the switching:

```
$(function() {
     $("#overlay").hover(function() {
          $("#image").css({
              "background": "url(myNewImage.jpg)"
          });
     }, function() {
          $("#image").css({
              "background": "url(myImage.jpg)"
          });
     });
});
```

It switches the images without problem. Issue is that there is a small delay while the images are switched so for a moment (less than second) you are able to see blank background (when #image div is not filled with either image).

On the other hand when you use plain CSS without jQuery to switch images like this (which is
not possible in this case) then there is no such delay.

So, using jQuery, how would you prevent this delay from taking place? Or is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the image you're loading in via jQuery is not preloaded.  When you switch out the image, the image takes a second to download.  When you have image URLs in CSS, all of those images are downloaded with the stylesheet.  The solution to your problem is to preload your images.

Comment: That is what I thought, but wasn't sure. Thanks.

Comment: @MatúšDúbrava I suggest to perform preload is obtaining those images in a hidden div `display:none` before your script. This will make sure that script will not be ready before downloading the images completely from the server.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure as I don't know the complete situation but from what information you are providing it should be possible with pure CSS as well:

```
#overlay:hover #image {
    background: url(anotherImage.jpg);
}
```

Regarding the delay in displaying the pictures, you could use a sprite. Place both pictures in one file (e.g. above eachother) and when hovering, change the background image position.

Comment: Unfortunatelly as I have stated it is not possible. DOM structure is too complex for CSS to handle this.

Comment: Are you sure? Because the CSS is just doing what your JS is doing. When the #overlay Div is hovered, the #image gets changed the background-image. If the id's are unique that should work well.

Comment: You can't use CSS selectors like this, it won't work.

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't see that the overlay div is coming after the image div ;-) Otherwise: http://jsfiddle.net/236uQ/

Answer (score 1):

what you need is to set multiple background image, so both images are **loaded**.
on hover , switch `background-position`.

Something similar to this:

```
$(function() {
     $("#overlay").hover(function() {
          $("#image").css({
              "background": "url(myNewImage.jpg) top left, url(myImage.jpg) 9999px 9999px"
          });
     }, function() {
          $("#image").css({
              "background": "url(myNewImage.jpg) 9999px 9999px, url(myImage.jpg)  top left"
          });
     });
});
```

```
#image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background:url(myNewImage.jpg) 9999px 9999px, url(myImage.jpg)  top left;
}
```